# Trouble using a subclass of SKLabelNode

Tags: swift, sklabelnode

I've written a custom subclass of SKLabelNode which should apply a rudimental "drop shadow" to my label:

```
class ShadowLabel: SKLabelNode {
    var shadowNode: SKLabelNode

    init(fontNamed font: String = "Foo", text: String, size: CGFloat, zPosition zPos: CGFloat, shadowColor: SKColor = SKColor.black, shadowOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -4), shadowAlpha: CGFloat = 0.5) {
        shadowNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: font)

        super.init(fontNamed: font)
        self.text = text
        self.fontSize = size
        self.zPosition = zPos

        shadowNode.text = self.text
        shadowNode.zPosition = self.zPosition - 1
        shadowNode.fontColor = shadowColor
        shadowNode.position = shadowOffset
        shadowNode.fontSize = self.fontSize
        shadowNode.alpha = 0.5

        self.addChild(shadowNode)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setNewText(_ newText: String) {
        self.text = newText
        self.shadowNode.text = newText
    }
}
```

My problem is, that at runtime, the console gives me the following error:

> use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class
>   'MyProject.ShadowLabel'

I use the custom subclass in my GameScene class as following:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var scoreLabel = (ShadowLabel(fontNamed: "Foo", text: "", size: 100, zPosition: 150, shadowColor: SKColor.black, shadowOffset: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -4), shadowAlpha: 0.5))

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        scoreLabel.text = "\(gameScore.totalScore)" // a struct which counts the game score
        scoreLabel.color = SKColor.white
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 100
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 150
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: Scene.width/2, y: Scene.heigth - 40 - scoreLabel.frame.height)
        addChild(scoreLabel)
    }
}
```

I don't know why the parameter-empty init() call is made in the first place.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to use the parameterless init method.

```
override init() {
    shadowNode = SKLabelNode()
    super.init()
}
```

You'll have to set your shadowNode to equal something which will probably break the other stuff you've got going on.

I tend to store my nodes just in the child array of the node so I don't have to deal with stuff like this, not sure if it's best practise though.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. As you have said, by overriding init() I lose all of the stuff that I've set up in my custom initializer, making my whole class unuseful.

Comment: I suppose you could make shadowNode nillable and then you wouldn't have to mess with it in the init? 
I'm not sure if this counts as an issue with my solution or an issue with your original implentation, as I said I wouldn't personally access nodes this way.

Comment: I didn't think about treating shadowNode as an optional, thank you for the idea! Anyway now I've found a non-elegant workaround to solve the problem, which I'll post in a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a non-elegant workaround to solve my issue (the additional overlayNode is required because, by treating shadowNode as a child of the main label node, it overlays the main node no matter what zPosition you choose, so overlayNode "restores" the shadow effect):

```
class ShadowLabel: SKLabelNode {
    var shadowNode: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Foo")
    var overlayNode: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Foo")

    init(fontNamed font: String = "Foo", text: String, size: CGFloat, color: SKColor, zPosition zPos: CGFloat, shadowColor: SKColor = SKColor.black, shadowOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -4), shadowAlpha: CGFloat = 0.5) {
        shadowNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: font)
        overlayNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: font)

        super.init(fontNamed: font)
        self.text = text
        self.fontSize = size
        self.zPosition = zPos
        self.fontColor = color

        shadowNode.text = self.text
        shadowNode.zPosition = self.zPosition - 1
        shadowNode.fontColor = shadowColor
        shadowNode.position = shadowOffset
        shadowNode.fontSize = self.fontSize
        shadowNode.alpha = 0.5

        self.addChild(shadowNode)

        overlayNode.text = self.text
        overlayNode.zPosition = self.zPosition + 1
        overlayNode.fontColor = self.fontColor
        overlayNode.position = self.position
        overlayNode.fontSize = self.fontSize

        self.addChild(overlayNode)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setNewText(_ newText: String) {
        self.text = newText
        self.shadowNode.text = newText
        self.overlayNode.text = newText
    }
}
```